# Using data from different activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 2 Activities namely **MainActivity** and **SubActivity**. How do i make that when `onCreate` of my **MainActivity**, the `EditText` in **SubActivity** will be checked if it has a text?

If it don't have a text, I want my **SubActivity** to start so I can input a text.

Comment: What do you meant by sub activity is it any popup or another class in which you are using edittext.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly in the starting of Main Activity check by using If statement whether there is some text or not  if there is text remain in that activity and if not then in the else statement use intent and call Sub Activity to insert the text .

Comment: yeah. but how can i check if there is a text in there? the intent and putextra won't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have not input anything to your sub activity's `edittext`(its empty) then it will open the sub activity and ask you for the text.

After entering the text to sub activity's `edittext` you have to store it. (Otherwise whats the use of that text.)

So make a static string variable which stores the value from your sub activity's `edittext`.

Now in your main activity instead of checking the sub activity's `edittext` just check the static string variable which you have created.

if it is empty
call the sub activity otherwise go with main activity.

I hope i have understood your problem.

Comment: yeah you got my problem right. But I can't understand your answer. :)